# remove unused dependencies in React

Tags: dependencies, npm, reactjs, package.json

How do I detect unused dependencies in a React project? I know there are npm packages that can do it, but they only work with normal js projects, not with Reacts jsx file. Is there a similar package that works with React?

Comment: if you run webpack through babel instead of jsx-loader, you don't need the jsx file type.

Comment: I want to use the jsx files, I think that is one of the benefits of doing React.

Comment: You can still use jsx markup. But babel doesn't require the ".jsx" extension.

Answer (score 15):

### Using depcheck to Track Dependencies

```
npm install -g depcheck
```

> This installs depcheck globally on your system.

#### Run the following command **inside** your folder where you want your dependencies to be checked.

```
depcheck
```

> Ensure that this folder contains the package.json file, otherwise **depcheck will not be able to track your dependencies.**

#### Let suppose you installed the **react-bootstrap** package and **did not import anything from it**.

Running `depcheck` gives the following output:

```
Unused dependencies
* ...
* react-bootstrap
* ... 
Missing dependencies
* ...
```

#### In general, you can **uninstall** any npm package or dependency by running the following command:

```
npm uninstall <package_name>
npm uninstall react-bootstrap
```

[npm-uninstall docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-uninstall)

Comment: Is it possible for depcheck to list packages that are actually needed as "unused"? I get a short list of 4, but feel like a couple are actually used by other packages.

Comment: @BenBalderas You're right, nice example is "expo-constants", it also doesn't resolve aliases (like `@screens/...`), you need to know what you actually installed just to use in the app's src

Comment: depcheck doesn't work that well. Lists a bunch of packages that are imported and used, so it's not 100% accurate. Because of that, it's manual checking anyway

Answer (score 7):

[try about depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck),Depcheck is a tool for analyzing the dependencies in a project to see: how each dependency is used, which dependencies are useless, and which dependencies are missing from package.json.

NOTE: Depcheck requires installed node version > NODE 10

Answer (score 7):

you can use [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check#on-the-command-line) for finding outdated, incorrect, and unused dependencies in your project.
After installing it you have to only run **npm-check** command in your terminal and it will list you status of your dependencies in your project

Comment: used yarn-check  rather than NPM-CHECK as yarn is my package manager but this answer led me to it.  Works great but doesn't offer uninstall option

Comment: `yarn global add yarn-check` to install globally